# Sync thumbnails on multisite for Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to generate thumbnails as I have new context for my media thumbnails. I was able to generate the thumbnails using the command:

```
php app/console sonata:media:sync-thumbnails sonata.media.provider.image
```

The issue is that my web app is multisite and the said command can only generate for default site. I've looked at the documentation but there is no option there for multisites. Is there any other way I can generate thumbnails for multisites?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the media format that I'm trying to sync is only under default context. It should also be under news context.

Comment: Did you really manage to sync for all websites. Executing the command do nothing in my projects. How did you regenerate all the thumbnails ?